Who or what is Gabriela Mistral's death-girl?
Gabriela Mistral's poem La muerte-niña is the first in  a group titled "Historias de loca" ("Madwoman's stories"). According to the first stanza, she was born in a cave, but according to the third stanza she was thought up by someone. According to the fifth stanza, she was crushed with a stone, but in later stanzas she is a two-year-old death (sixth stanza), then she has been death for seven years and still dying (tenth stanza) and later "Death was thirty years old" (14th stanza).
In the second stanza, the world was still certain of God's support, but the eighth stanza is reminiscent of myths explaining the origin of disasters and natural phenomena generally:

The mornings grew dull,
noon became clumsy (or sullen*);
every sun learned its sunset
and every fountain its drought.

(*: "sullen" is Ursula K. Le Guin's translation.)
According to the penultimate stanza, "our second Earth was entering its (or her) epiphany".
I can't make much sense of this poem. Simply dismissing it as an imaginary madwoman's story sounds too easy.
Here are some of the questions to which I have no answer.

Is the death-girl Death itself? If yes, how could she have been thought up? If no, what does she actually represent?
If she is only two years old in the sixth stanza, how can Nimrod (the great-grandson of Noah) and Ulysses have seen her?
What is the "second Earth"? Is it the same Earth mentioned in the third stanza or was that the first Earth?
Who is the speaker of the poem? A madwoman, as suggested by the title of the group of poems? What does she try to achieve by going into people's houses and crying, "It's a seven-year-old death who is still dying"?

Who can interpret this poem?

Below is an attempt at translation:

-In that cave she was born to us,
and as no one would think,
she was born naked and tiny
like the poor baby pigeon.
So whole was the world!
so strong it was at noon!
so armed as the pine cone,
certain of the God that supported it!
Some of us thought it
as one thinks villainy;
the Earth consented to it
and that cave opened up for him.
Out of that hole he suddenly emerged
with that flesh of elegy;
she came out groping and crawling
and she was barely distinguishable.
With a stone she was crushed,
with a fist she was squeezed.
She swayed like a reed
and with the wind she fell...
I stood on the road
to shout to whoever heard me:
It's a two-year-old death
who is she still dying!’
Recious (?) raptors found her,
strong females crossed the track;
Nemrod and Ulysses looked at her,
but none understood...
The mornings were debased,
the noon became clumsy;
Each sun learned its sunset
and every fountain its drought.
The prairie learnt autumn
and the snow its hypocrisy,
the beast its weariness,
the flesh of man its agony.
I went into house after house
and to every man I would say:
‘It's a seven-year-old death
who is still dying!’
And I stopped shouting my cry
when I saw that they went to sleep.
They already had I don't know what I left
and I don't know what melancholy...
We began to be the kings
who know the afterlife
and the beast or the creature
that was the servant wounded us.
Now the breath was parting
and now the blood was lost,
and the song of the mornings
like a horn was hoarse.
Death was thirty years old;
it would never die again,
and the second Earth of ours
was opening its Epiphany.
I tell it to those who have come,
and they laugh with insanity:
‘I am one of those who danced
when Death wasn't born...’

